# Find local minima/maxima

Tags: sqlite

I need a query to update the value at the point from which the metrics rises or decreases .For example I have a table with

```
ID      METRICS  INDICATOR
1        204.4 
2        205
3        206        H
4        204
5        199
6        198        L
7        204
8        205        H
9        201
10       199
```

If you see the above table the metrics column the reversal of metrics happens . The point the reversal happens should be updated with the indicator value H/L as shown in the indicator column.

Answer (score 0):

You want a "H" when both the preceding and the following rows have smaller values:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Indicator = 'H'
WHERE Metrics > (SELECT Metrics
                 FROM MyTable AS T2
                 WHERE T2.ID < MyTable.ID
                 ORDER BY ID DESC
                 LIMIT 1)
  AND Metrics > (SELECT Metrics
                 FROM MyTable AS T2
                 WHERE T2.ID > MyTable.ID
                 ORDER BY ID ASC
                 LIMIT 1);
```

You want a "L" when both the preceding and the following rows have larger values; use a similar query.

Comment: Yes ........ this is what I was looking for .You made my day . Appreciate for your great help - Mandi